# GLGE: drop shadows

Tags: webgl, glge

I'm keen on webgl and GLGE framework.
I can't make my cube drop shadow onto a plane. I've copied the definition of light from GLGE shadow demo and I still don't see shadows.

What should I take into account to make objects drop shadows in GLGE?

Comment: Best way to see what's going on might be to gradually transition from the GLGE demo to your scene.  You might find that, for example, your geometry is out of the light's range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the script used by http://www.glge.org/demos/newshadow/ is different from one in 0.8 release.